# switch String java para 1.6

Tags: java

Tengo una aplicación en Java con la Version JRE 1.6 y estoy utilizando el código Switch de la siguiente manera:

```
private Node viviendaFamiliar(Element padre, ObtenerPolizaSptoCanalResponseDocument polizaSptoCanal) throws Exception{
        Node IDENVIVIENDA = XMLUtilidades.aniadeNuevoElemento(padre, "IDENVIVIENDA");
        try{
            RiesgoBO[] listaRiesgos = polizaSptoCanal.getObtenerPolizaSptoCanalResponse().getMssObtenerPolizaSptoCanal().getListaRiesgoArray();
            for(RiesgoBO datoRiesgo :  listaRiesgos){
                Element hijoIDENVIVIENDA = XMLUtilidades.aniadeNuevoElemento(padre, "REGISTRO");
                AtributoBO[] listaAtributos = datoRiesgo.getListaAtributoArray();
                for(AtributoBO datoAtributo : listaAtributos){
                    String campo = datoAtributo.getCampo();

                    switch(campo){
                    case "MCA_PROTECCION_AGUA":
                        //codigo
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return IDENVIVIENDA;
    }
```

El problema que no me deja utilizar el switch de un String a no ser que sea la Versión 1.7 y esta aplicación no se puede cambiar a dicha versión. Otra opción seria utilizar "Enum". ¿Como debería utilizarlo para este caso? En caso de haber otra opción agradecería que se me indicara.

Si necesitáis más información no dudéis en pedírmelo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Porqué tiene que ser un switch-case? Podrías hacer lo mismo con if-else-if para cada opción, comparando la cadena campo con los valores que necesites.

Comment: Como dice @SuperG280, si la única feature de Java 7 que quieres usar es el switch con strings, no te compliques y haz un un bloque de if's de toda la vida. De todas formas puedes crear código en una versión superior de Java y compilar para una versión inferior. El cómo hacer esto dependerá del IDE que uses o si usas consola y si usas Maven o similar (busca parámetro -target). Si te decides a compilar a una versión inferior tendrás que comprobar las incompatibilidades para no llevarte sorpresas: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#incompatibilities

Comment: Como son muchos valores que tiene el String campo, me resultaba más cómodo que else-if, pero podría utilizarlo como recurso.

Comment: Vas a tener tantos else if como cases en un switch. Al final es lo mismo.

Comment: Al final lo cambiare por los else if como me comentáis los dos. Esta previsto pasar esta aplicación a Maven y convertirlo a la 1.7 o a la 1.8 pero aún no se cuándo. Muchas gracias a los dos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me respondo a mí mismo: Al final lo cambiare por los else if. Esta previsto pasar esta aplicación a Maven y convertirlo a la 1.7 o a la 1.8 pero aún no se cuándo.